# Using xml templates from SharePoint Online Doc Lib in PNP Provisioning

Tags: document-library, pnp-provisioning

I'm crafting PNP Provisioning XML templates for use on team sites and storing them into a SharePoint document library for use in PowerShell scripts.

Each time I run the Apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate command I'm getting the following error.

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : File not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path $xmllistitems.FieldValues.FileRef
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.ApplyProvisioningTemplate
```

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
$Password=Get-content "[MY Password Path]\SecurePW\ckcpw.txt"|ConvertTo-SecureString
$userCredential=New-Object system.management.automation.pscredential($mysources.AdminUPN,$Password)
$adminSiteUrl = "https://"+$mysources.Org+"-admin.sharepoint.com"
Connect-SPOService $adminSiteUrl -Credential $userCredential

#Connect-PnPOnline -url ($MySources.sourceurl) -Credentials $userCredential 

connect-pnponline -url "https://[tenant]/sites/CKCShareptDev" -Credentials $usercredential

$XMLList=get-pnplist "xmltemplatebak"
$xmllistitems=get-pnplistitem -list $xmllist -id 3 -fields "FileRef", "File_x0020_Type","FileLeafRef"

foreach($Item in $xmllistitems){

    #Write-Host $Item['FileRef'] + " " + $Item['File_x0002_Type']+ " " + $Item['FileLeafRef']

    Connect-PnPOnline -url "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/ProvTest" -Credentials $usercredential
    Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path $item['FileRef']     }
```

Can't figure out how to access the file to use in the Apply-PNPProvisioningTemplate command.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the specific template file reference like below from the document library :

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/templatestorage/Documents/template.pnp
```

**Or**

From your existing code, download the PnP template file from the document library to a **temp** folder, then refer the PnP template file from the **temp** folder location like below :

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "C:\temp\template.xml"
```

Then after applying the PnP template from temp folder, delete the template file.

Note :

Download and deletion can be handled through the PowerShell code in the same apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate script only.

For various other ways of referring PnP template refer to the below MSDN article :

[Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: The first solution didn't work (or I was doing it wrong).  The template is located in a document lib as follows:  tenant/sites/CKCShareptDev/XMLTemplateBak/ so by your example the url to use in the apply should be tenant/sites/ckcshareptdev/xmltemplatebak/template.xml  This failed...was trying to avoid downloading the file but I think I may have to.